# PHP - Image resizing class in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, class

I have created a function for resizing WordPress image based on

http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/create-images-thumbnails-and-cache-them-php-287.html

but I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class image_resize
```

but I have not called this class befor.

**here is my function**

```
function resize_image($thumb_id){
        //check for thumbnail cache if not then create it
    $attachment = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'large');
    $image_url = pathinfo($attachment[0]);

    if (file_exists(get_template_directory().'/images/thumbs/' . $image_url['basename'])) {
      // 2592000 = 30 days
      if ( time() - filemtime(get_template_directory().'/images/thumbs/'.$image_url['basename']) > 2592000 ) {
        unlink(get_template_directory().'/images/thumbs/'.$image_url['basename']);
      }
    }
    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory().'/images/thumbs/' . $image_url['basename'])) {
      include(get_template_directory().'/inc/image_resize.php');
      // if cache file does not exist then create it.
      $originalImage = new imageResize($attachment[0]);
      $originalImage->size_width(120);
      $originalImage->save(get_template_directory().'/images/thumbs/'.$image_url['basename']);
    }
}
```

please tell me whats wrong with it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including `image_resize.php` which has already been included before. Therefore you try to execute the `ImageResize`class declaration two times, thus the error you get.

Replace your `include` with [include once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) and take some time to read its documentation and what it means.

Comment: @HowToPlease: glad it helped, if your issue is fixed please remember to accept the answer